# Counting number of 'negative' cells for each ID

Tags: matlab, count

I want to count how many 'negative' cells there are for each unique ID. What am I doing wrong here? I then want to display how many ID's have one or more negative counts and how many ID's have three or more negative counts.

my code:

```
clc
clear
close all

data = {
'vajbfch07wu11y90'  'negative'
'ekvpmhqybu920hnr'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'eddbdv5bsqggeydq'  'negative'
'6vmhbj7041fe7xck'  'negative'
'6vmhbj7041fe7xck'  'negative'
'6vmhbj7041fe7xck'  'negative'
'6vmhbj7041fe7xck'  'negative'
'j5d6dgzbeynyyg02'  'negative'
'j5d6dgzbeynyyg02'  'negative'
'j5d6dgzbeynyyg02'  'negative'
'v21tstcp164uya6g'  'negative'
'v21tstcp164uya6g'  'negative'
'brjmfpunj00rn92c'  'negative'
'brjmfpunj00rn92c'  'negative'
'mb8nggnegcwq9nqc'  'negative'
'vk4ga34492m01hwv'  'negative'
'vk4ga34492m01hwv'  'negative'
'vk4ga34492m01hwv'  'negative'
'vk4ga34492m01hwv'  'negative'
'd9hk2zeexhxp2h0v'  'negative'
'f93xk5sq60ehp34j'  'negative'
'f93xk5sq60ehp34j'  'negative'
'ypzzn212hqvwjtc9'  'negative'
'0q2mmnq0wb97z7bm'  'negative'
'jh8k1dd9g2p2d218'  'negative'
'2e5tr0scw89z68kg'  'negative'
'2e5tr0scw89z68kg'  'negative'
'5zb72reqnsxnzuca'  'negative'
'5zb72reqnsxnzuca'  'negative'
'5zb72reqnsxnzuca'  'negative' };



[sigma, ~, uidx] = unique(data(:,1));
counts = accumarray([uidx, 2-data(:,2)], 1);
sigma = [sigma, counts];
sigma
```

error message:

```
Operator '-' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'.

Error in count_ex (line 45)
counts = accumarray([uidx, 2-data(:,2)], 1);
```

Comment: This code will never run; your `data` variable is all bungled. None of the strings therein are predefined as variables, let alone `6vmhbj7041fe7xck`, since variables cannot start with a number. I know you imported this data, given [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75056392/5211833), so please add that (just call `data` in your command window and copy the output). It's probably a table with strings, i.e. `'vajbfch07wu11y90', 'negative'` etc. That way we can actually run this code and get the error you mention, rather than a syntax error.

Comment: @Adriaan i have edited the question - is that okay now?

Comment: have you looked at the `data` variable in your workspace? You're using char arrays so this will basically end up as one big matrix. You should either be using curly braces `{'like','this'}` or `"strings"`

Comment: @Wolfie i have changed this now and am getting an error message displayed in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the new dictionary type in R2022b to count occurences and at the same time get unique items:

```
d = dictionary(data(:, 1), 0);
for entry = transpose(data(:, 1)); 
    d(entry) = d(entry) + 1;
end
```

If that is not available:
It seems all entries are labeled 'negative', so you just need to count occurences in column one, see https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115838-count-occurrences-of-string-in-a-single-cell-array-how-many-times-a-string-appear

```
c = categorical(data(:, 1));
[categories(c), num2cell(countcats(c))]
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. How would I then make a bar plot to show the number of occurrences of each count? So frequency on the Y axis and then on the X-axis the 'count'.

Comment: your description of what goes on which axis does not make much sense to me, but you probably want something like `barh(countcats(c)); set(gca, 'YTickLabels', categories(c))`, see https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329953-how-to-create-bar-graph-with-categorical-data

Comment: I have made a new question